# If I delete a game, will it also delete my saves?

Tags: ps4, no-mans-sky

How do you delete No Man's Sky on ps4 without it deleting the rest of the saved files?

Comment: This question is easily answered by Google and the PlayStation website.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the *title* question, **no**. You *can* delete a game from the HDD without it deleting your save game data and files.

To answer the *body* question - under settings, you go to where you manage storage (navigation is self-explanatory and easy to figure out if you're a first time user). You'll be able to delete game data AND save data, indicating these are two *separate* files. Delete **only** the game data and if you decide to reload the game later, you will pick up right where you left off.

I've done this countless times.